# Sort Posts By Custom Field Date?

Tags: post-meta, date, post-type

I have the following code displaying posts from a custom post type. However, I need them displayed in date order from information put in a custom field, can this be done?

I try this code :-

```
$course = new WP_Query( 
    array ( 
        'posts_per_page' => '10' , 
        'post_type' => 'course',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'course_date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ) 
);
```

But it shows me data like this :-

```
30-12-2014
28-9-2014
26-10-2014
19-12-2014
```

It must be like :-

```
30-12-2014
19-12-2014
26-10-2014
28-9-2014
```

What can I do?!

Comment: There is a plugin i wrote that does all kind of post/page ordering, also by custom fields. maybe you can use it as well: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-order-by

Answer (score 2):

Use `meta_value` instead of `meta_value_num`

```
<?php    $course = new wp_query( array ( 'posts_per_page' => '10' ,
                                         'post_type' => 'course',
                                         'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                         'meta_key' => 'course_date',
                                         'order' => 'DESC'
                                        )
                                );
?>
```

Comment: i try but it not work good, the result :- `30-12-2014 , 28-9-2014 , 26-10-2014 , 19-8-2014` , its not true

Comment: @user3704392 are you storing the date in dd-MM-YYYY format?

Comment: Yes, i sort like  dd-MM-YYYY

Comment: I don't think it's possible to sort date in that format as the meta table store everything as varchar. You should store in timestamp value or in `YYYYMMDD` format if you want to query like this.

Comment: I saved like YYYYMMDD

Comment: @user3704392 Now sorting with `meta_value` should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$course = new WP_Query( 
    array ( 
        'posts_per_page' => '10' , 
        'post_type' => 'course',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num date',
        'meta_key' => 'course_date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ) 
);
```

Just add a 'date' in after the 'meta_value_num' in 'orderby' as per reference https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sorting-by-custom-field-date-and-post-date/ and I also verify it by use of this code.

Comment: This is not the same case. It's about sorting by a custom field that contains the date.